# How do I alter an HTML page that is currently visited so that the user sees it?

Tags: http, server, arduino, esp32

I'm working on a small project at the momment, using an ESP32, and the Arduino IDE.

I set up a basic server interface via multiple `client.println` commands.
Basically there is one button, that lets me start a stepper motor. There's also an IR sensor hooked up. I would like to give the user a notification on the open page, as soon as the IR sensor gives a signal.

I tried with printing to the serial monitor in Arduino IDE to check the functionality of the sensor and it works there. Now, my thought was that I could just do

```c++
if(detection == LOW) {
   // Serial.print("obstacle detected\n");
   client.println("<strong><font size=(5) color='#ff4f23'>SOME KIND OF MESSAGE</font></strong>");
}
else{
   // Serial.print("no obstacle!\n");
}
```

But unfortunately it doesn't do the trick.

Could somebody please guide me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

After the webside is loaded on the client side, it is static. You delivered the HTML once, and the Client/Server Connection is closed afterwards. Rewriting does not deliver your new HTML Code to the Client.

What you could do:

Use some sort of polling with AJAX and JavaScript. Let your webside check for updates every 60 Seconds for example.

Comment: I've tried adding: <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1"> which I thought would reload the page, but it didn't. Not sure if I didn't place it right or something but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

another option is add:

```
<script>setInterval(function(){location.reload();},1000)</script>
```

in your html.

**Advice**

The best solution should be a static html index page
with javascript that performs requests to an API and changes the page consequently.

in this way you need to download only changes and you the whole page (a really bad thing if you have images on it)